# ScrollView, LinearLayout chaos

Tags: android, android-activity, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I today added a scrollview to my app. I wanted something like google now cards. It worked, but I want it to be fullscreen, but on the bottom. On the bottom i got a EditText and a Button and i want the scrollview to stop there, so that they are both visible. How can i do that? :s
That's my activity:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/chat_layout"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_linkrholoorange"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    tools:context=".Chat"
                    android:text = "Now">


        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true" >

        <com.linkr.chat.NowLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#e3e3e3"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/card"
                        style="@style/nowCardStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        tools:context=".Chat"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout"/>

            </com.linkr.chat.NowLayout>
        </ScrollView>



        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/chatTextArea"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sendButton"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sendButton"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="What's on your mind..."
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

            <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@drawable/social_send_now"
                    android:onClick="sendMethod"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scrollView"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <!--<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawerimage"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/desert"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"></ImageView>-->
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#F3F3F4"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:hint="What's on your mind?"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" ></ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: This is the app]

I hope you can help me
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said what is happening so its hard to say what the problem is. However, yo make this the way it sounds you want I would suggest adding the property

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

to your `LineareLayout` with the `EditText` and the `Button`. See if that works. Something like

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="10dp"
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">   <!-- Add this line here -->
```

The parent of your `EditText` and `Button` is a `LinearLayout` but they have properties such as these

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sendButton"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sendButton"
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView"
```

but these are properties of a `RelativeLayout` so they won't have any effect, at least not any wanted effect, on `View`s whos parent is a `LinearLayout`.

See [The Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) for the properties that each `ViewGroup` has.

Comment: I want the scrollview to be fullscreen. it isn't. there's a black frame around it. And i want the LinearLayout to be on top of it/i want the scrollview to stop where the LinearLayout starts.

Comment: Yes, so did you try my solution? Did it achieve that? If not, how so and maybe I can adjust my answer?

Comment: yes, kind of ^^ but the other problem is, that i can't put anything outside of the scrollview. And I need the scrollview to be fullscreen

Comment: What do you mean, "i can't put anything outside of the scrollview."? And have you added `i can't put anything outside of the scrollview.` to the `<activity>` tag in your `manifest.xml`? You can't make just the `ScrollView` full screen

Comment: There's this black frame around the scrollview and i can't put anything into this black frame. The scrollview doesn't use the whole place.

Comment: Might have to do with your `padding` and `margin`, have you tried taking that out? Also, did you add the xml line I suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: do you know, how i can set the length of the scrollview? i want it to end where the Linearlayout starts

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by the length? How many `Views` it has?

Comment: The scrollview is overlapping the linearlayout. i want it to end where the linearlayout starts.

Comment: You might try adding `android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"` to the `ScrollView`